# Odd dimensional Density Matrix construction with Pauli matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

A basis for the density matrix operators is the Pauli Matrices set, but if i'm understanding correctly all Pauli matrices are square and even dimensional, since they are kronecker products of the basic pauli matrices, then maybe they're a base for just even dimensional density operators? if yes there's a way to write odd density operator only as Pauli matrices?

Comment: There are higher dimensional versions of Pauli matrices; 3x3 version exist, say. But the ones that forms a basis for the density operator should be only the 2x2 case.

Comment: *A basis for the density matrix operators is the Pauli Matrices set* - could you cite the source for this claim? They probably have something rather specific in mind.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos No i needed to know if you could write, let's say a 3x3 matrix as linear combination of pauli matrices and Identity operator, i mean if tehre are any tricks to do it since the simple linear combination can't reproduce a 3x3 matrix

Comment: The problem is that i don't know if just tensoring them can make an odd density matrix, but if i use geller matrix can i could map the subspace described by that matrix in maybe a 4x4 subspace made of tensored Pauli matrices?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Starting from Pauli matrices and taking tensor product, you only get powers of two, not all even dimensions. -- But of course there are many other bases, the Pauli matrices are just one choice. In particular, there are many ways which reduce to the Paulis in the case of 2x2 matrices.

Comment: Also, the $n \times n$ versions of the Pauli matrices (i.e., the spin operators for a spin-$(2n+1)$ system) can't form a basis for the space of $n \times n$ matrices because there simply aren't enough of them.  The number of such matrices is always 3 (4 including the identity) while the space of $n \times n$ matrices is $n^2$-dimensional.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It really depends in which sense you generalize the Pauli matrices. The spin operators are far from being the only natural generalization.

Comment: As indicated in my answer, you need ***three*** sets of Pauli matrices, with one (free!) dependence condition, to cover the eight degrees of freedom of a 3x3 hermitian density matrix, augmented by the identity for the nontrivial trace. But you *must* stop thinking about *su(2)*.

Answer (score 2):

A 3×3 hermitian matrix may be represented by a real-coefficient linear combination of the eight *su(3)*-basis [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices#Matrices),
$$
\lambda_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad  
 \lambda_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad  
 \lambda_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  , \\
 \lambda_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad  
 \lambda_5 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \\
 \lambda_6 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \quad
 \lambda_7 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad  
 \lambda_8 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}  ,
$$
augmented by  the 3×3 identity one. Here is a trick.

As you were taught, the Gell-Mann matrices are essentially the Pauli matrices ***embedded in a 3×3  space***, where I represent them as such with the upper-left superscript labelling the row and column left blank (zero entries),
$$
\lambda_1=~ ^3\sigma_1, \qquad \lambda_2=~ ^3\sigma_2, \qquad \lambda_3=~ ^3\sigma_3, \\
\lambda_4=~ ^2\sigma_1, \qquad \lambda_5=~ ^2\sigma_2, \qquad \qquad \qquad   \\
\lambda_6=~ ^1\sigma_1, \quad \lambda_7=~ ^1\sigma_2, \quad \lambda_8=\tfrac{1}{ \sqrt 3} \left(~ ^2\sigma_3 +~ ^1\sigma_3\right )=\tfrac{1}{ \sqrt 3} \left(~ ^3\sigma_3 +2~~ ^1\sigma_3\right ) ~, \\
$$
which you then augment by the  3×3 identity, $$1\!\! 1=\tfrac{1}{2}
\left((~^1\sigma_3)^2+ (~^2\sigma_3)^2+(~^3\sigma_3)^2\right).$$